# Back to Top Button For Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html

http://themeforest.net/item/retro-portfolio-one-page-vintage-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/1708109

I wish to create something similar to this, however there is a nifty button that takes a person back to the top of the page, as well as a static header DIV.

Would be a case that i make the top div fixed?

```
#div{position: fixed; }
```

also would the back to top function use:

```
"<a href="#top">LINKING TEXT HERE</a>"
```

But with some CSS styling?

thanks
Kirsty

Comment: yes, you can create a div with position fixed to get that effect

Comment: Hi Dorel, not sure if u have seen the site. But it appears that it skips to loads of different DIVs. How can that be created? thanks

Comment: the efect is created with javascript. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147283/jump-to-anchor-tag-without-showing-hashtag-in-url for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very nice plugin you can use to achieve this. You can find it here : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-to-top/