# How can I make my page scroll to the middle on load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this question has been asked before but I did not find the solution on those previously asked questions.

Can someone please help me figure out how to scroll my page to a certain spot on when I refresh the page or when I first come in to my page?

Comment: What do you mean by "spot". A certain element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to scroll to certain anchor/div on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757625/jquery-how-to-scroll-to-certain-anchor-div-on-page-load)

Comment: The questions you've seen asked before **do** have answers. If you want to say those answers didn't work for you, you must show what you're working with, what you tried, and describe what you expected vs. what you saw. There's no point in simply saying "I want to do X, I know this has been answered, but it didn't work for me" with no detail whatsoever. It's a waste of your time and ours.

Answer (score 1):

Well, use on of the solutions below depending on what you need. If you want a "smooth scroll" ypu can search on SO for it. There are a lot of threads covering both this and that.

```
$(window).scrollTop(200); //to scroll 200px

var targetOffset = $('#yourelement').offset();
$(window).scrollTop(targetOffset.top); //scroll to a certain element
```

[jQuery API on scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop-value)

[Smooth scrolling on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/MMgXu/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an anchor at the point you want to scroll to. On page load you can use jQuery to scroll to that anchor. More here: [Jump to anchor tag without showing hashtag in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147283/jump-to-anchor-tag-without-showing-hashtag-in-url)

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Yeah... and it's an answer, isn't it?

Comment: It is someone elses answer. And only because he can't comment doesn't make something that is usually commenworth suddenly an answer

Comment: Someone woke up on the wrong side of the bed this morning...  :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scrollTop( $("#middle").offset().top );
```

If you have an element in the middle of the page with ID of #middle, the above code will do the trick.   So adjust as needed to scroll to the part of the page you need.